# Detecting modifications of UDP or TCP packets

Tags: networking, tcp, web, udp

Is there some mechanism to detect that a UDP or TCP packet was modified by others?
Good methods are welcome.

Comment: Describe your scenario and requirements in more detail, please. There's not enough information here to answer well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable method for TCP / UDP integrity checking is encapsulation inside a cryptographically secure layer. E.g. [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec).

Comment: But IPsec is the only generic solution that would work with any potential TCP or UDP packet.